# Generating GCP compatible Cloudflare SSL certificate

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-platform, openssl, cloudflare

I'm trying to configure SSL for Google Cloud's App Engine.
You can upload your own custom SSL certificate + private key in GCP (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ruwy.png)).

I'm using Cloudflare for DNS, and would like to use the "Full (strict)" SSL policy in Cloudflare. This would mean I have to add a certificate and key, created by Cloudflare, in GCP (in same screenshot).

I've managed to convert the private key to a valid (PEM) format that GCP will accept. The only thing not working is the Certificate part.

When entering both certificate and key in GCP, upon clicking upload, the following error is returned:

```
The certificate data is invalid. Please ensure that the private key and public certificate match.
```

After some googling, I found the following resources [on GCP's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#converting_private_keys_and_concatenating_ssl_certificates), explaining I need a have the full *certificate-chain* uploaded in the certificate field. So next thing I tried, is to *concat* my certificate from cloudflare together with the [root certificate](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507#h_30cc332c-8f6e-42d8-9c59-6c1f06650639) of cloudflare itself, as explained in the GCP docs.
So I ran the following command to create this chain:

```
cat domain.crt cloudflare-root-ca.crt > concat.crt
```

... and uploaded that one in GCP in the certificate field.

That didn't work either, even while the checksums of both private key and the certificate-chain match as [explained by GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#converting_private_keys_and_concatenating_ssl_certificates), by running:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in concat.crt | openssl md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in myserver.key.pem | openssl md5
```

...and comparing the md5 outputs.

So now I'm completely without Idea's. GCP's error messages are limited to the one above, and one other saying your PK is not a valid format.

### Same problems when trying via CLI (gcloud)

When trying this process through the cli `gcloud`, we get the same errors.
Trying the following command:

```
gcloud app ssl-certificates create --display-name example.com --certificate ./cloudflare-concat.crt  --private-key cloudflare-pk.key
```

...yields the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.ssl-certificates.create) 
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid certificate. 
`CertificateRawData` must contain a PEM encoded x.509 public key certificate, with header and footer included, 
and an unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key, with header and footer included and with size at most 2048 bits. 
The requested private key and public certificate must match.
```

Any help on uploading a valid certificate (from Cloudflare) and private key in GCP is much appreciated.

### Update 1

I found this [(cached) paged](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:z5TlwGV24hkJ:https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001186052-What-intermediates-and-roots-are-Cloudflare-issued-certs-signed-against-+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=be) describing all the root and intermediate certs of Cloudflare. I've tried a couple of them to concatenate agains my domain cert, but no luck so far. It's also not clear which one to use...

### Update 2

I've beginning to think that this won't work, ever. Because I'm using an 'Origin Certificate' from Cloudflare, I believe this is a self-signed cert from Cloudflare itself, meaning that App Engine won't ever recognize this as valid.

The reason I think this is the case, is because I tried to use the `cfssl` tool from cloudflare to 'create a bundle-cert' automatically. The response I get from running

```
cfssl bundle -cert domain.crt
```

Returns the following result:

```
[INFO] bundling certificate for {Country:[] Organization:[CloudFlare, Inc.] OrganizationalUnit:[CloudFlare Origin CA] Locality:[] Province:[] StreetAddress:[] PostalCode:[] SerialNumber: CommonName:CloudFlare Origin Certificate Names:[{Type:2.5.4.10 Value:CloudFlare, Inc.} {Type:2.5.4.11 Value:CloudFlare Origin CA} {Type:2.5.4.3 Value:CloudFlare Origin Certificate}] ExtraNames:[]}
{"code":1220,"message":"x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"}
```

### Extra info

- I'm using a free Cloudflare subscription.
- Everything works fine when using the 'flexible' setting from Cloudflare,
- But I would like to use the 'full (strict)' setting

Comment: Try using an online ssl certificate verify to see if anything is wrong with the files that you are importing: https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html

Comment: @JohnHanley tried it, everything looks in order

Comment: @Andries App Engine now supports Cloudflare Origin CA certificates. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37087010/6303504

Comment: Thanks for the link @Andrei, meanwhile I was able to solve it according to the steps explained in the blogpost I mention in the answer below.

Comment: I have the same problem but cloudflare is not involved and the headers are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a recent blogpost, describing how to solve this.
After following the steps described, the certificate was accepted in Google Cloud, and everything worked for the 'full (strict) ssl' option in cloudflare!

In short: it involved a bit of tweaking the keys, by manually adding 'RSA' to it, as described in the blogpost.

See this link:
https://blog.woohoosvcs.com/2019/11/running-google-app-engine-behind-cloudflare/

EDIT:
This is probably the same end-result as using the shell commands as described by @Andrei

Answer (score 0):

Can you please verify you are using free Cloudflare or paid Cloudflare account. 
Because if you are free using than I think SSL strict is not going to work make it flexible and redirect all HTTP request to https request.

Comment: I've updated my question. I'm using a free cloudflare sub. But would like to use the full-strict option from this free account.

Answer (score 0):

simply:

what you get from cloudflare is:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
wXYZ....
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

change it to:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
wXYZ....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and google app engine accepts it.